# I am using pandas for reading an excel image file which is attached below

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

records = pd.read_excel('TerraData USERS.xlsx')

df1 = records.loc[records['PWD LAST MODIFIED DT'] == '20180528', ['USER ', 'PWD LAST MODIFIED DT', 'PROFILE', 'LAST_LOGIN DATE', 'LOGIN TIME']]

print (df1)
```

I am using the code above to search the entries in 2nd column of Excel file that are dates on which password was changes.

[image: [Sample entries]

I want to search passwords changed in 2018. I have tried doing it with the script above but I got no result and no error simply says empty.

If some could help wold be very grateful.

Comment: please include your code as a part of the question. also, please provide some sample input and output.

Comment: import pandas as pd

records = pd.read_excel('TerraData USERS.xlsx')                                             
df1 = records.loc[records['PWD LAST MODIFIED DT'] == '20180528', ['USER ', 'PWD LAST MODIFIED DT', 'PROFILE', 'LAST_LOGIN DATE', 'LOGIN TIME']]
print (df1)

Comment: I want to print all the entries of year 2018

Comment: If you got an error message you should include the message with its full traceback.

Comment: I tried your code but it did not work on the provided image. Please make sure to include everything for a [mcve].

Comment: It worked as Pawan kumar has sited it below. Thank you everyone for your support and help. :)

Comment: And sir I was not getting any error. I was getting the result "Empty Index" and no  error it was running successfully. I have cited it above if you have read my post. I have written that i got no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest **a greater than date** instead of a **equals date** to search passwords changed in 2018 like so..

```
df1 = records.loc[records['PWD LAST MODIFIED DT'] > '01/01/2018', ['USER', 'PWD LAST MODIFIED DT', 'PROFILE', 'LAST_LOGIN DATE', 'LOGIN TIME']]
```